# Rails: Where "params" is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-3

I use `params` in my controller like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:aircon])
    ...
  end
end
```

Is `params` an attribute of `ApplicationController` ? I guess not, because it does not have the `@` prefix. So, what actually `params` is ? Can I use it in any custom method in `ProductsController` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's defined in ActionController::Metal. ApplicationController inherits from ActionController::Base, which inheirts from ActionController::Metal. If you look at the Rails API at http://api.rubyonrails.org/, you will find `params` is just a function that returns the paramaters of the `request` object.

Answer (score 7):

The parameters are actually being parsed in middleware called [ActionDispatch::ParamsParser](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb#L23). The `params` function in `ActionController::Metal` is a wrapper for this.